# Using multiple NICs to balance load in windows

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, routing, bridge

I have a computer with 3 NICs: A, B, C.  A is connected to the internet.  B is connected to a 24 port switch and that switch is connected to another 24 port switch.  These switches contain embedded computers.  Now these NICs are gigabit, and I need faster speed, so I want to connect NIC C to one switch and NIC B to the first switch, effectively giving me 2 gigabits of throughput.

How would I configure this?  If it could act as a single network that would be best.  Would I do a bridge between the 2 ports?  If so, would this give me the double the bandwidth?

Also would it be possible to get internet from the NIC A to be sent to NICs B and C?

All of this makes it sound like I am just trying to build a generic router on my system by having NAT and DHCP, a virtual switch with 2gbps capacity, and a 2gbit virtual nic connected to the virtual switch.

System:  Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Look up "teaming". (that's the term hp uses). Its up to the manufacturer, but what you want to do is set up teaming, and have the nics share the load.

Comment: Windows server has that NIC teaming feature. You've to install that for that feature.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 with Realtek NICs so teaming is not supported from what I have seen.